# How to increment values in a list within specific range

Tags: python, list, numpy, loops, increment

I have a list `l =[253, 59, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` and I want to set a range of `(0, 255)` for each element in the list. I want to implement it in **python**. I want to **increment** the **elements** **one by one** such that when it reaches the max range the element should **reset to 0** and the **next element should increment by 1**

The output should look like this after every iteration:

```
l =[253, 59, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
l =[254, 59, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
l =[255, 59, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
l =[0, 60, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
l =[1, 60, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
.
.
.
.
l =[255, 60, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
l =[0, 61, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: "*I want to implement it in python*" then why did you tag it `numpy`?

Comment: I want to know whether there is a way to do it using numpy lib as well. since numpyarrays are faster to work with compared to lists.@mozway

Comment: since you will need to iterate, I doubt numpy will be of much help, can you let us know if the input should be arbitrary? e.g. if `l = [255, 255, 255, 7, 0]`, then the next iteration should be `[0, 0, 0, 8, 0]`?

Comment: yes the input should be arbitrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option in pure python:

```
l = [253, 59, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

pos = 0
n_iter = 10
step = 0
for step in range(n_iter):
    for pos in range(len(l)):
        if l[pos] < 255:
            l[pos] += 1
            break
        else:
            l[pos] = 0
    print(f'step {step+1}: {l}')
```

Output:

```
step 1: [254, 59, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
step 2: [255, 59, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
step 3: [0, 60, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
step 4: [1, 60, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
step 5: [2, 60, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
step 6: [3, 60, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
step 7: [4, 60, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
step 8: [5, 60, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
step 9: [6, 60, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
step 10: [7, 60, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

One way with a loop:

```
def inc_list(l):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        l[i] += 1
        if l[i] > 255:
            l[i] = 0
        else:
            return

for _ in range(300):
    print(l)
    inc_list(l)
```

Alternatively, a recursive solution:

```
def inc_list(l):
    if not l:
        return []
    elif l[0] == 255:
        return [0] + inc_list(l[1:])
    else:
        return [l[0] + 1] + l[1:]

for _ in range(300):
    print(l)
    l = inc_list(l)
```

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: one-liner is

```py
import struct
list(struct.pack('<Q', struct.unpack('<Q', bytes(start))[0]+1))
```

### 1- Counting in 64 bits

Just to provide another view, this what you seem to do is counting in a list of 8 bytes representing a 64 bits integer, little-endian... Why don't you just do that?

```py
def plusOne(l):
   n=0
   b=1
   for dg in l:
       n+=b*dg
       b*=256
   n+=1
   res=[]
   for i in range(len(l)):
       res.append(n%256)
       n//=256
   return res
```

As is, this answer is not faster than the others. It is even way slower, I surmise (haven't timeit it. But, well, it is obviously more complex).

But if what you want to have is just a counter, then you could simplify by keeping just an integer as state value, and generate the list

### 2- Iterator

```py
def listCounter(start, size):
    while True:
        res=[]
        x=start
        for i in range(size):
            res.append(x%256)
            x//=256
        yield res
        start+=1

myiter=listCounter(254, 8)
print(next(myiter))
print(next(myiter))
for _,l in zip(range(20),listCounter(510,8)):
    print(l)
```

### 3- Struct (using internal representation)

Since that is how 8 bytes integer are counted on the hardware, you can even rely on the cpu to do that, rather than trying to imitate it in python.

```py
import struct
l=[254, 255, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
nextl=list(struct.pack('<Q', struct.unpack('<Q', bytes(l))[0]+1))
```

Or in the for of an iterator

```py
import struct
def listCounter(start):
    while True:
        yield start
        start=list(struct.pack('<Q', struct.unpack('<Q', bytes(start))[0]+1))

for _,l in zip(range(10), listCounter([254,255,0,0,1,0,0,0])):
   print(l)
```

```
[254, 255, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[255, 255, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[4, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[5, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[6, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[7, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

### Explanation

`bytes(l)` is a byte array containing the 8 bytes in `l`
`bytes(l) -> b'\xfe\xff\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00'`
Those 8 bytes are the 64 bits representation of a number. Which we can extract by `struct.unpack`, specifying the format `<Q` (64 bits integer, little-endian, that is increasing first bytes first)
`struct.unpack('<Q', bytes(l)) → (4295032830,)`
It is in form of tuple because we could have asked for a succession of different numbers. So
`struct.unpack('<Q', bytes(l))[0] → 4295032830`
We can increment it
`struct.unpack('<Q', bytes(l))[0]+1 → 4295032831`
And we can get the 64 bits bytes array representation of this new integer, using `pack`
`struct.pack('<Q',struct.unpack('<Q', bytes(l))[0]+1) → b'\xff\xff\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00'`
This bytes array are just numbers between 0 and 255, we can easily get them converting it to a list
`list(struct.pack('<Q',struct.unpack('<Q', bytes(l))[0]+1)) → [255, 255, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is equivalent to finding representations of consecutive integers in positional numeral system with base 256 (but you could use mixed bases as well).

#### `numpy` ravel and unravel

For smaller lists you could find integer that has a form `l = [253, 59, 2, 0]`

```
value = np.ravel_multi_index(l, [256] * 4, order='F') #sets value to 146429
```

And then use [np.unravel_index](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html) to get back representations of first, say, 5 integers:

```
np.transpose(np.unravel_index(np.arange(value, value+5), [256]*4, order='F'))
>>> array([[253,  59,   2,   0],
           [254,  59,   2,   0],
           [255,  59,   2,   0],
           [  0,  60,   2,   0],
           [  1,  60,   2,   0]], dtype=int64)
```

#### Larger cases

In your case dimension = `[256] * 8` is required. This is too large because integers can't exceed `2**63` in `numpy` and `ValueError` would be thrown. In this case you could implement your own way that replaces `np.ravel_multi_index` and `np.unravel_index`:

```
shape = np.cumprod([1, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256], dtype=np.int64)
value = np.dot(l, shape) #same 146429

def unravel(values, shape=[256] * 8):
    steps = len(values)
    result_arr = np.empty(shape=(len(shape), steps), dtype=int)
    for j in range(len(shape)):
        result_arr[j] = values % shape[j]
        values =  values // shape[j]
    return np.transpose(result_arr)

unravel(np.arange(value, value+5))
>>> array([[253,  59,   2,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
           [254,  59,   2,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
           [255,  59,   2,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
           [  0,  60,   2,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
           [  1,  60,   2,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]])
```

Note that only 8 iterations are required in all cases so it should be faster than Python - only ways.

Answer (score 0):

with loop,

```
array = [253, 59, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
index = 0
while index < len(array):
    while array[index]<256:
        array[index] += 1
        print(array)
    array[index] = 0
    index += 1
```